# theme.json is altering Group block HTML

Tags: hooks, theme.json

I am creating Blog within the existing site which will have completely different look, styles, features and functionalities.

I need theme.json only on the Blog pages, but the problem is that theme.json is altering the HTML of Group block, and messing up the whole site.

To be more precise, it is removing the `wp-block-group__inner-container` div from Group block.

I need to either prevent this altering of HTML by the theme.json, or to completely stop loading it when I am on the blog.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to prevent the unwanted altering of HTML by using the `render_block_core/group` filter, and a copy of [wp_restore_group_inner_container](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.0/src/wp-includes/block-supports/layout.php#L246-L273), without the JSON support check.

```
public static function my_add_block_group_inner( $block_content, $block ) {
        $tag_name                         = isset( $block['attrs']['tagName'] ) ? $block['attrs']['tagName'] : 'div';
        $group_with_inner_container_regex = sprintf(
            '/(^\s*<%1$s\b[^>]*wp-block-group(\s|")[^>]*>)(\s*<div\b[^>]*wp-block-group__inner-container(\s|")[^>]*>)((.|\S|\s)*)/U',
            preg_quote( $tag_name, '/' )
        );

        $replace_regex   = sprintf(
            '/(^\s*<%1$s\b[^>]*wp-block-group[^>]*>)(.*)(<\/%1$s>\s*$)/ms',
            preg_quote( $tag_name, '/' )
        );
        $updated_content = preg_replace_callback(
            $replace_regex,
            static function( $matches ) {
                return $matches[1] . '<div class="wp-block-group__inner-container">' . $matches[2] . '</div>' . $matches[3];
            },
            $block_content
        );
        return $updated_content;
    }
add_filter( 'render_block_core/group', 'my_add_block_group_inner' );
```